# ModX Eform: Captcha not generating image

Tags: captcha, modx, modx-evolution

I am trying to get CAPTCHA working on the eForm plugin. I have added the input form field:

```
<label for="cfCaptcha">Captcha:<br />
<img src="[+verimageurl+]" alt="verification code"><br />
<input id="vericode" name="vericode" class="text" type="text">
```

and I have added

```
&vericode=`1`
```

to the eForm call.

and have added the Template Variable `[+verimageurl+]` to my template.

However, when I preview the form all I see in the image area is `<img src="" alt="verification code">`

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this fixed?

Check that you ended the label code. Run it through w3c code checker too.
A few times I have left a element un-closed and it breaks the whole thing.